# Xcode 5.1 and Simulator In Use Error

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ios-simulator

I've noticed that since upgrading to Xcode 5.1, the "Simulator In Use" error pops up randomly when trying to build/run. Sometimes nothing happens, and other times I get the error.

Even if there are no apps running, or the simulator is not running at all, I still encounter the error, which persists until I restart Xcode.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: My solution is here. More like a brandade though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22266953/the-simulator-cant-be-launched-because-it-is-already-in-use

Answer (score 4):

Fix this issue using below approach :

1. **Quit the simulator and Xcode as well.**

OR

1. Reset the content of Simulator. Goto to **"iOS Simulator"** menu -> **"Reset contents and Settings.."**

Comment: first solution worked for me, second is doing nothing without restarting both (xcode, iosimulator) too

Answer (score 2):

When Ever you get an error like "Simulator In Use"  Just follow the following steps.  
1 ) Just remove derived data for the particular application. ( or all the derived data for not needed).
2 ) Delete Derived data also from trash folder if any.
3 ) Clean Your Project.
4 ) Build and run the Project.

Comment: Thank you for the info about Derived Data.  Never knew it was OK to clear that out!!  However it is not the solution to this issue; my problem still persists.  I now believe this might be a glitch peculiar to Xcode 5.1.

Comment: yeap, same with me. simulator in use and wont start, restart XCode fixes it. so it is a bug, I believe

Answer (score 2):

Quitting the xCode and restarting solves the problem but it has become, at least with me, perpetual. I have to quit and restart again so many times already. There's got to be a fix for this.

Comment: This is the correct answer for me. There's no need to reset and even restart the simulator, restarting Xcode fix this.

Answer (score 0):

The upgrading Mac OS version from 10.8.5 to 10.9.2 fixed this issue for me.

Comment: Ok, I'll upgrade today and c :)